# SwiftUI Reload View after dismissing a sheet

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I have a bool value in UserDefaults to check if user is logged in or not.
In my first page I have a Header where when user click the profile pic it shows a modal (using .sheet) and inside that I have a button for user to LogOut.

How can I change the View when user presses the LogOut button and dismisses the modal?

Or how can I reload the main page after user clicks the LogOut button and dismisses the modal in order to check the new Bool value?

```
struct Home: View {

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {   
                // MARK: Header
                Header(title: "Home")    
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(20)
    }
}

struct Header: View {

    public var title: String = ""
    @State private var showProfile = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            // MARK: - User Profile
            Image("profile")
                .resizable()
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("⚠️ Profile has been tapped.")
                    self.showProfile.toggle()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showProfile) {
                Account(showProfile: self.$showProfile)
            }

        }
    }
}

struct Account: View {

    @Binding var showProfile: Bool

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            // MARK: - Account Sections
            List {

                // MARK: - Log Out -
                Section {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("❌ User has been logged out.")
                        self.showProfile.toggle()

                    }) {
                        Text("Log Out")
                            .bold()
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                }
            }

                // MARK: - NavigationBar Settings
                .navigationBarTitle("Account", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my UserDefault class

```
class UsersSettings: ObservableObject {

    @Published var isLoggedIn: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLogged") {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.isLoggedIn, forKey: "isLogged")
            print(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLogged"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you ever get a solution for this? I am having a simular issue where when the sheet if viewed and then dismissed the List View which had items in the list is now blank. So I would need to know how force the ListView to refresh when the sheet is dismissed?

Comment: @Learn2Code in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcaQVlj8_uw), I noticed that this person did what I was looking for and after checking it I noticed that the person used something called "NotificationCenter" and I did the same and now it's working for me. You can learn more about NotificationCenter in [here](https://learnappmaking.com/notification-center-how-to-swift/)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I was looking for from this video:
[Login Page Using Firebase With SwiftUI - Integrating Login Page With Firebase Using SwiftUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcaQVlj8_uw)

Comment: This was downvoted because it's a link-only answer which can become obsolete, and then the answer helped nobody.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say, what is your goal. Maybe this will meet your requirements
1) when user tap on image, the sheet appear
2) user can log in or out, or simply dismiss the sheet with swipe down gesture
3) user image reflect log in / out status

```
import SwiftUI

class LoginModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loggedIn = false
}

let loginModel = LoginModel()

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = loginModel
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                // MARK: Header
                Header(title: "Home", loggedIn: model.loggedIn)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(20)
    }
}

struct Header: View {

    public var title: String = ""
    var loggedIn: Bool
    @State private var showProfile = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            // MARK: - User Profile
            Image(systemName: loggedIn ? "photo.fill.on.rectangle.fill" : "photo.on.rectangle")
                .resizable()
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.showProfile.toggle()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showProfile) {
                Account(showProfile: self.$showProfile)
            }

        }
    }
}

struct Account: View {

    @Binding var showProfile: Bool
    @ObservedObject var model = loginModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.model.loggedIn.toggle()
                        self.showProfile.toggle()

                    }) {
                        Text(model.loggedIn ? "Log Out": "Log In")
                            .bold()
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Account", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

the result looks like

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to show the user the login page again (which will shows at first lunch for the first time) when the user clicks the logout button. and in ur code i want to check for the UserDefault value on the ContentView() to see if it's true show the home view, if false show the login view and when user clicks the logout dismiss the sheet and show the login view

Comment: @user3441734 did you ever get a solution for this? I am having a simular issue where when the sheet if viewed and then dismissed the List View which had items in the list is now blank. So I would need to know how force the ListView to refresh when the sheet is dismissed?

Comment: @Learn2Code solution for what? the code in my answer works as expected (and described above) To be honest, I don't understand "arata's" notice ... copy - paste - run this code and you see the value in the List updated as required.

Comment: @user3441734 can you go see my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60662263/issue-with-swiftui-listview-when-sheet-is-presented-and-then-dismissed

Answer (score 0):

`UserSettings` is the source of truth and must be used in your sheet modal view (`Account`).

Add a binding to this object in the Home or Header view to observe changes and update your interface accordingly.

You declare an object binding like this:

```
struct Home: View {
  @ObservedObject var userSettings: UserSettings
  // ...
}
```

Then you observe changes like this:

```
struct Home: View {
  // ...  
  var body: some View {
    if userSettings.isLoggedIn {
      Text("User is logged in")
    } else {
      Text("User is not logged in")
    }
  } 
}
```

For this to work you have to log out the user I your Active view.

Comment: It didn't change anything, I still need to close the app and re-open it to see the changes